# Does anyone remember what the statement/command "WaitOn" meant in VB3?

Tags: vb6

In the Form_Load event of this ultralegacy app I need to transliterate over to a web app is this command/statement "WaitOn" that occurs right after the On Error GoTo...

Does anyone remember what WaitOn means?

Here's the code snippet:

```
Dim sCmd As String
Dim iFileHandle As Integer
Dim sFileName As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim sKeyWord As String
Dim sWindowPosition As String
Dim iWindowState As Integer
Dim sSystemId As String
Dim sMetrics() As String

On Error GoTo MainFormLoadErr
WaitOn
ReDim gsFundsUsed(0 To 0)
ReDim gsObjectsUsed(0 To 0)
Set gsActiveSpread = Nothing
.
.
.
MainFormLoadExit:
WaitOff
Close
Exit Sub

MainFormLoadErr:
MsgBox Error$(Err) & " in MainForm Load"
Resume MainFormLoadExit
```

There is a corresponding WaitOff down there I just found.  I don't think WaitOn is part of a line label.

---

As @C-Pound Guru suggested, WaitOn and WaitOff were methods in one of the (many) modules of the program.  Not clear from the the names of the subroutines was the fact that their task was to set the mouse pointer to the Wait Cursor, and then return to the default, later.

```
Sub WaitOn ()
  On Error Resume Next
  Screen.MousePointer = 11
End Sub

Sub WaitOff ()
  On Error Resume Next
  Screen.MousePointer = 0
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow.  I've seen some fugly VB code in my day but.....yechhhh!

Comment: Agreed, but I don't think VB3 had enumeration-style values like it does today, so perhaps this was the best they could do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've never come across a 'WaitOn' or 'WaitOff' command in VB.  You might want to double-check the code to see if there's a WaitOn method written (and a WaitOff method as well).  It's not a label as VB labels end with a colon (:).

Comment: Bingo.  Looking thru the code for a login method I ran into both WaitOn and WaitOff.  VB3 doesn't have a right-click context menu so no Go To Definition.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you right-click and Go To Definition? And does the code currently run?
Check the references - maybe it's something from a non-standard dll.

Comment: VB3 doesn't have a right-click context menu so no Go To Definition.  Unfortunately, or this question never would have been asked.